# How to use NativeScript UI’s Calendar

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm new in NativeScript. I'm trying to use **NativeScript UI's Calendar** in my angular project. for using it, I've installed NativeScript UI's Calenda Plugin `tns plugin add nativescript-ui-calendar`. 
Now when I insterted following code into my html component:

```
<navigation:ExamplePage xmlns:navigation="navigation/example-page" xmlns:calendar="nativescript-ui-calendar" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
  <navigation.actionBar>
    <ActionBar title="Getting Started" />
  </navigation.actionBar>
  <calendar:RadCalendar id="calendar" />
</navigation:ExamplePage>
```

I returns some errors on builing time like this:

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error calling module function 

Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "crypto", relative to: app/tns_modules/
    com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:146)
    com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:55)
    com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
    com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:542)
    com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:534)
    com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(
NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
....
...
```

please show me an example using calendar in angular.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly scenario you are trying to achieve, but you can start very easily with the Calendar in the {N} Playground. In this sample you can find a simple initialisation of the component: [{N} Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=cGc9aq)

Comment: I download it and try to building it but it has some errors on building time. I use NativeScript Sidekick for building apps.

Comment: It had some errors on building time. Finally I found the problem. I changed `Build Type`  to **Cloud**  in `NativeScript Sidekick` and now it build successfully without any errors.anyway thanks